# What is the difference with 'protected' and 'protected-static' variables?

Tags: java, oop, static, protected

I read a book for OOP and 
an example about 'protected' access modifier is strange for me.

**Summary of example**

1. This example is to test how 'protected' reserved word effects to variables.
2. ClassA has 2 protected variables (static / non-static)

   ```
   package a;

   public Class A {

       protected int a;
       protected static int b;
   }
   ```

3. ClassB is derived from ClassA and located another package
4. ClassB.test has a method to check accessibility (Cannot run)

   ```
   package b;

   public Class B extends ClassA {

       ClassA x = new ClassA();

       // [O] : Executable
       // [X] : Not-executable
       void test() {

           a = 1;   // [O] : Derived from ClassA
           b = 1;   // [O] : Derived from ClassA

           // [X] : a is protected, so only accessible within codes in derived class
           x.a = 1; // A) 

           // [O] : I don't know why it is executable
           x.b = 1; // B) 
       }
   }
   ```

Actually, b is 'protected' so I thought it cannot be accessed by instance variable like **x.a = 1;**

But it can be accessible with 'static' keyword.
How can I understand for this?

**Shortly A) is fine, but why is B) executable ?**

Comment: I did not understand your post,please make it more clearer

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: Can you update your sample code to show us precisely where the compiler errors are?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry for convenience. I marked compiler error as [X] - Not-executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `static` keyword means that variable belongs to the class itself instead of the objects of said class. You could replace your call to `x.b` with `ClassA.b`. Since `ClassB` extends `ClassA`, all `protected static` variables are accessible for all methods of `ClassB` at all time.